# How to display array in MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Hello friends I get datas from Web services so I can't use Html.DisplayFor(model=>model.item)and how can I display datas in array. Here is my code:

```
@using icerik.TahakkukServices


@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Deneme";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout5.cshtml";
}


@{
    TahakkukServicesClient client = new TahakkukServicesClient();
    client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "service_test";
    client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "";
    client.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode = System.ServiceModel.Security.X509CertificateValidationMode.None;
    MakbuzList[] liste = client.GetMakbuzListe(2);

}

 @foreach (var item in liste)
 {

Html.DisplayFor(item.Adi)
                }
```

Comment: Does this really belong in the view?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to display an array in MVC3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12214620/how-to-display-an-array-in-mvc3)

Comment: This is absolutely not the way MVC should be used. What happened to the M and the C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@model icerik.TahakkukServices. add your table name

```
@{ 
    ViewBag.Title = "Deneme"; 
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout5.cshtml"; 
} 


@{ 
    TahakkukServicesClient client = new TahakkukServicesClient(); 
    client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "service_test"; 
    client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = ""; 
    client.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode = System.ServiceModel.Security.X509CertificateValidationMode.None; 
    MakbuzList[] liste = client.GetMakbuzListe(2); 

} 

 @foreach (var item in liste) 
 { 

Html.DisplayFor(model=>model.) add your column name
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Allright I understand how to do it just giving model name with your Service as you can see at below

```
@model icerik.TahakkukServices.Borc
```

so you can use Html.DisplayFor