# What is the reason DisplayFor ignores html attributes?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

When trying to use this

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.someField, new { htmlAttributes = "class = someclass" })
```

the field, when rendered does not contain class someclass. I supposed its because its just writing out the text and there isn't a span element or anything to set the class on.

I'm really looking to set the id so that I can update it via js later on.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6365633/what-is-the-html-displayfor-syntax-for

Comment: DisplayFor(), does not have any HTML attributes, thus u can't do it. Instead there are other ways of rendering the data inside a DIV/SPAN with ur class..

Comment: I think it should be @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.someField,  new {@class="someClass"})

Answer (score 8, accepted):

class needs to be `@class`

This comment is valid

> DisplayFor(), does not have any HTML attributes, thus u can't do it.
>   Instead there are other ways of rendering the data inside a DIV/SPAN
>   with ur class.. – Nick Oct 16 at 11:15

This comment is also valid

> I think it should be @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.someField, new
>   {@class="someClass"}) – Michel Oct 16 at 11:30

Comment: You can also use a capital-C in class as opposed to @class: `new {Class="someClass"}`

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me (for example, when model is Url):
[Razor view to DisplayFor DataType.Url that opens in new window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16648127/razor-view-to-displayfor-datatype-url-that-opens-in-new-window)

"You could override the default template by adding a file in ..."