# Razor view to DisplayFor DataType.Url that opens in new window

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

How do I make links open in a new window with Razor and DisplayFor?

I have a property which is `DataType.Url`,

```
[DataType(DataType.Url)]
public string SiteUrl { get; set; }
```

Using `@Html.DisplayFor` this is converted into an `a` tag.

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.SiteUrl)
```

However I need it to open in a new window. Setting `new {target="_blank"}` does not add the attribute for target

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.SiteUrl, new {target="_blank" })
```

It is just this one page where I need the functionality of opening in a new window so using JavaScript seems a bit excessive.

How do I get the links to open in a new window?

Comment: try adding @ before target, with class you need to add @ before it since its a keyword

Comment: `DisplayFor` renders a `span` tag, you need an `a` tag for that.

Comment: @mattytommo, in ASP.NET MVC 4 there's a default template for that which renders an anchor.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Ah really? For `DisplayFor`? You got a link? I'm interested.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could override the default template by adding a file in `~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/Url.cshtml` with the following contents:

```
<a href="@ViewData.Model" target="_blank">@ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue</a>
```

Comment: This would mean that all links would open in a new window. Is there a way for the template to apply **only** to the viewmodel in question?

Comment: Yes, you could name your template for example `~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/NewWindowUrl.cshtml` and then decorate your view model property with the `UIHint` attribute: `[UIHint("NewWindowUrl"), DataType(DataType.Url)] public string SiteUrl { get; set; }`. Now only view model properties decorated with this UIHint attribute will use the custom template and others will use the default one.