# Getting a value from @Html.DisplayFor and @Html.HiddenFor

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

The HTML

```
    int i = 1;
    foreach (var item in Model.MyDataset)
    {
    <td class="tdBorder">
    @Html.DisplayFor(x => item.ID, new { id = "VisibleID" + @i })
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => item.ID, new { id = "HiddenID" + @i })
    </td>
    i += 1;
    }
```

The jQuery

```
 for (i = 1; i <= rowCount; i++) {
            var myID_Visible = $.trim($("#VisibleID" + i).val());
            var myID_Hidden = $.trim($("#HiddenID" + i).val());
        }
```

I'm trying to learn some MVC and jQuery.

Would some one explain to me why calling

`var myID_Visible = $.trim($("#VisibleID" + i).val());` returns an empty string but

`var myID_Hidden = $.trim($("#HiddenID" + i).val());` returns the value of my item.ID?

The only difference is that the first jQuery line refers to a @Html.DisplayFor (returns empty string) while the second jQuery line refers to a @Html.HiddenFor (returns actual value).

Why can't i get a value from the @Html.DisplayFor?

Answer (score 3):

Because `@Html.DisplayFor()` does not render a control and you cannot use `.val()`. Instead use

```
myID_Visible = $.trim($("#VisibleID" + i).text())
```

although this will depend on the html that `@Html.DisplayFor()` is rendering (are you using a display template?). You need to check the html generated.

By default `DisplayFor` will just render the text value of the property. You would need to do something like

```
int i = 1;
@foreach (var item in Model.MyDataset)
{
  <td class="tdBorder">
    <span id="@i">
      @Html.DisplayFor(x => item.ID)
    </span>
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => item.ID, new { id = "HiddenID" + @i })
  </td>
  i += 1;
}
```

and in the script

```
myID_Visible = $.trim($('#' + i).text());
```

Comment: .text() still returns an empty string on @Html.DisplayFor()

Comment: As I said, check the html that `DisplayFor` generates. By default it will just render the text (in which case you cant access this way). If you have a display template then it will depend on what surrounding elements are being rendered.

Comment: I've edited answer with possible solution for accessing the value. But note your should **NEVER** render controls (`HiddenFor()`, `TextBoxFor()` etc) in a `foreach` loop like this

Comment: like i said i'm just getting started with MVC/jQuery. Any specific reasons why rendering controls (HiddenFor(), TextBoxFor() etc) in a foreach loop like this this is not recommended?

Comment: That's why I mentioned it :). By using a `foreach` loop your rendering controls with duplicate `name` attributes so there is no way that the colletion can be bound to you model when posting back. You need to use a `for` loop `for(int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++) { @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].ID) ....}`. This will correctly name the controls with indexers `<input name="[0].ID" ..> <input name="[1].ID ..>` etc

Answer (score 1):

Some input has .html() rather than .val() try:

```
var myID_Visible = $.trim($("#VisibleID" + i).html());
```

**EDIT**

Another thing, remove the @ before the i, you are already inside a C# code

```
@Html.DisplayFor(x => item.ID, new { id = "VisibleID" + i })
```

Comment: .html() still returns same result as .val()

Answer (score 1):

The reason is explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41930753/how-to-add-id-to-html-displayfor) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12913234/what-is-the-reason-displayfor-ignores-html-attributes).
For your case however, I prefer to make it like this:

HTML

```
int i = 1;
foreach (var item in Model.MyDataset)
{
  <td class="tdBorder">
    <p id="VisibleID@(i)">@Html.DisplayFor(x => item.ID)</p>
    <p id="HiddenID@(i)">@Html.HiddenFor(x => item.ID)</p>
  </td>
i += 1;
}
```

So in the script we can call it:

```
for (i = 1; i <= rowCount; i++) {
    var myID_Visible = $("#VisibleID" + i).text();
    var myID_Hidden = $("#HiddenID" + i).text();
}
```

Hopefully this can help you, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
@Html.DisplayFor(x => item.ID, new { id = "VisibleID" + @i })
```

rendred html looks like:

```
<span id="VisibleID1">item id value here</span>
```

whereas

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x => item.ID, new { id = "HiddenID" + @i })
```

rendered html looks like

```
<input type="hidden" id="HiddenID1" value="item id value here">
```

So in order to have display for value you should you use, `$("#VisibleID1).html()` as noted by @Shadi