# How to add id to @Html.DisplayFor

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to add id to

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ScreenWidth, new { @id = "width"})
```

and then use

```
document.getElementById("width").innerHTML = w;
```

Why is it not working?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `DisplayFor` helper doesn't generate any HTML tags, it just outputs the formatted text. So you cannot add `id` attribute to it. What you could do instead is to wrap it in a tag (div or span):

```
<div id="width">
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ScreenWidth)
</div>
```

and then be able to manipulate the contents of this tag:

```
document.getElementById("width").innerHTML = w;
```

Comment: That HTML.DisplayFor is not generating any HTML tags is wrong, at least in ASP.NET core 3.1. It returns an instance of IHtmlContent. When using HTML.DisplayFor with a boolean it generates an input of type checkbox. <input checked="checked" class="check-box" disabled="disabled" type="checkbox">. The problem with your approach is that for every HTML.DisplayFor we need to wrap a div around, then use javascript.

Answer (score 1):

One other approach to this is to create a customised Display Template that you can then use to render both the value and, say, a `<span>` tag that contains your `id` attribute.

### If you want your id set to something custom, rather than the name of the property:

Create a file called SpanWithId.cshtml in Views\Shared\DisplayTemplates (create any of those folders if they are missing) and add this code:

```
<span id="@(ViewBag.HtmlID)">@Model</span>
```

And then in your view, you can use it like this:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ScreenWidth, "SpanWithId", new { HtmlID = "project-name" })
```

That code is an adaption from [Phillip Smith's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1341219/phillip-smith) answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10208664/1879019)

### If you want your id and name set to the name of the property:

Create a file called SpanWithIdAndName.cshtml in Views\Shared\DisplayTemplates (create any of those folders if they are missing) and add this code:

```
@{var fieldName = ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix;}
<span id="@fieldName" name="@fieldName">@Model</span>
```

And then in your view, you can use it like this:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ScreenWidth, "SpanWithIdAndName")
```

That code is an adaption from [David Clarke's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/132599/david-clarke) answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5722732/1879019)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use this as well

```
      <span id="width">@Html.Displayfor(model => model.ScreenWidth) </span>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are just wanting to display a label.  This is how I accomplished this.

```
<label id="lblName">
    @Html.Raw(@Model.ObjectA.ObjectB.ObjectC.ToString())
</label>
```

Then if I want to change the value in jQuery, I can:

```
$('#lblName').text("New Value");
```