# how i select a val() on button click from this following list view ,

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

here a CRUD TYPE LIST IEnumerable WorkingPlace.Models.PerchesDetail

when the  list is on screen and i click on button i need all fields value  ,
but lots of try i cant get ,

html

```
                    @foreach (var item in Model)
                    {
                        <tr style="background-color:#eff6de">
                            <td class="hfr">
                                @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.PerTranChallanId, new { @class = "PerTranChallanId" })
                                @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.PTranCode, new { @class = "PTranCode" })
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SypplyerName ,new {@class="sn", @id = "SypplyerName" })
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ChallaNo)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ChallaDate)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TaxAmount)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TotalAmount)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Showchl1", new { id = item.PerTranChallanId , PTranCode=item.PTranCode }) |
                            </td>
                            <td class="con">
                                <input type="submit" id="convt" name="convt" value="Add To INv No:- @ViewBag.NewINVNo1" class="convt btn btn-success " />
                            </td>
                            <td class="csl">
                                <input type="submit" id="cansel" name="cancel" value="Cancel From INv No:- @ViewBag.NewINVNo1" class="convt btn btn-danger " />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                </table>


            </div>
```

here i need all item. element value  by using jquery

```
    $(document).on('click', '.convt', function () {

            alert("OK");
            var spn = $(this).prop("#SypplyerName").text();
           //var spn =$(this).prop("#SypplyerName").val();
            var aaa = $(this).closest("tr").html("#SypplyerName").val();


            spn1 = $(this).prop(".sn").val();
            //spn1=$(this).prop(".sn").text();
            aaa1 = $(this).closest("tr").html(".sn")val();
            //aaa1 = $(this).closest("tr").html(".sn").text();
            var nnn = $(".sn").text();

            alert(spn);
            alert(aaa);
            alert(spn1);
            alert(aaa1);
            alert(nnn);
        });
```

this is try of different type but i can gate this value

need help

Answer (score 0):

DisplayFor can not have id, see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41930753/how-to-add-id-to-html-displayfor) for your reference.

So provide id to your outer HTML tag, and access using id.
ex:
In HTML:

```
  <td id="sypplyerName">
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SypplyerName)
    </td>
```

In JQuery you can access the same using:

```
var sName=$('#sypplyerName').text();
```

Comment: its alert  blank massage  ,$(document).ready(function () {
   $(document).on('click', '.convt', function () {
    alert("ok");
    var sName = $('#sypplyerName').text();
    alert(sName);
   });

  });  first alert get OK , then blank alert

Comment: thanks i get correct answer var sName = $('#sypplyerName').text().trim();,

Comment: #Ashvani mishra ,Thanks .