# How do i add ID to HTML helpers in razor view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i want to add ID's for table fields.  The reason i want to add id's is to apply java script. the code is for one of the field

```
<th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.YearCompleted)
        </th>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add id to @Html.DisplayFor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41930753/how-to-add-id-to-html-displayfor)

Comment: `@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.YearCompleted, new { id = @Model.IdField })`