# Set id to @Html.Textbox on MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to set id to `@Html.TextBox` so that I can access it in JavaScript. How can I do it?

```
@Html.TextBox("Output")
```

Note that I don't want to make a property for this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add id to @Html.DisplayFor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41930753/how-to-add-id-to-html-displayfor)

Comment: @MartinCostello No. Those answers have a model, I don't want to use model.

Comment: As you can see in the suggested answer, it's the same, you just pass null as the model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an overload to do this:

```
@Html.TextBox("Output", null, new { id = "put-your-id-here" })
```

Where I put `null` is the `value` argument, which is of type `object`.

The third argument is the `htmlAttributes` argument, which lets you define every attribute possible, you could also set classes passsing an object like this:

```
new { id = "main-card", class = "card card-body" }
```