# How just use display template for field

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have a model:

```
public class SomethingViewModel 
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Customer")]
    public string SomethingName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Something id")]
    public string SomethingId { get; set; }

}
```

I need to create a view for `Html.EditorForModel` but I need field SomethingName only display(label). How to do this?

**UPDATE: I need use attributes**

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6365633/what-is-the-html-displayfor-syntax-for

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to individually setup your `LabelFor`s and `EditorFor`s. Try something like:

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.SomethingName)
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.SomethingName)

@Html.LabelFor(m => m.SomethingId)
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.SomethingId)
```

Or for just displaying:

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.SomethingName)
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.SomethingName)

@Html.LabelFor(m => m.SomethingId)
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.SomethingId)
```

Comment: I update my post. I need work with Html.EditorForModel and atributtes

Comment: @simplydenis The above works for attributes, but `EditorForModel` doesn't actually display the labels, that's why you'll have to do that yourself. Otherwise you'd have to create your own editor template for your model.