# How to display a string property of Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am sure this is very simple, but I haven't found it yet.

I have an Model with a property of Message that I will set in the control.

What is the Html helper for this?

For example,

```
Html.TextBoxFor(m=> m.Message)
```

shows me the message, but it's in a textbox.  I don't want the textbox, just the value.

Greg

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use two syntax:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Message)
```

or

```
@Model.Title
```

You can read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6365633/what-is-the-html-displayfor-syntax-for) for details.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `@Model.Message` ?