# MetadataType attribute is not working for details view in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I am newbie in entity framework and I have created `Ado.Net Entity Data model` which contains two properties `FullName` and `EmailAddress`. what I am trying to do is that in my details view I want to display `Full Name` instead of `FullName`. To accomplish this I have written code like this:

```
namespace ScaffFolding.Models
{
 [MetadataType(typeof(EmployeeMetaData))]
 public partial class Employee
 {

 }
 public class EmployeeMetaData
 {
    [Display(Name="Full Name")]
    public string FullName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Email Address")]
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
 }
}
```

My `edmx` file also sharing the same namespace and have same class named as `Employee`
 
 Now the problem is that in `Details` view this code is not working means showing `FullName` instead of `Full Name` but in `Create` view it's working as expected.
Here is code for my `Detail` view:

```
@model ScaffFolding.Models.Employee

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}

<h2>Details</h2>

<fieldset>
<legend>Employee</legend>

<div class="display-label">FullName</div>
<div class="display-field">
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FullName)
</div>

<div class="display-label">Gender</div>
<div class="display-field">
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Gender)
</div>

<div class="display-label">Age</div>
<div class="display-field">
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Age)
</div>

<div class="display-label">HireDate</div>
<div class="display-field">
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.HireDate)
</div>

<div class="display-label">EmailAddress</div>
<div class="display-field">
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.EmailAddress)
</div>

<div class="display-label">Salary</div>
<div class="display-field">
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Salary)
</div>

<div class="display-label">PersonalWebSite</div>
<div class="display-field">
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.PersonalWebSite)
</div>
</fieldset>
<p>
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=Model.Id }) |
@Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</p>
```

Can anyone please tell me what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

DisplayFor is used for picking up templates from DisplayTemplates folder.
more at [What is the @Html.DisplayFor syntax for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6365633/what-is-the-html-displayfor-syntax-for)

Where as, LabelFor picks stuffs from data annotations

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got the answer what is going wrong here. The problem is in the code generated by VS:

Visual Studio is generating the `Details` view using div tag as shown below

```
<div class="display-label">FullName</div>
```

Where as `LabelFor` is being used by Vistual Studio for `Create` view:

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.FullName)
```