# using model in view, lambda expression explain

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, lambda, html-helper

In the following code of the example application of VS2015:

```
@model LoginViewModel

<p>                               
 @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Name)                                       
</p>
```

I want to know how the compiler knows that `m` refers to the `LoginViewModel` if I never said that `m` is an alias for `LoginViewModel`.

And I would like help understanding the lambda expression of `DisplayNameFor`. Why it requires a lambda if we could just pass the string `m.Name`? How is it used here?

Comment: you can [follow the instructions in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383192/compile-views-in-asp-net-mvc) to pre-compile your views, and see what the razor engine is doing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The given Razor template will be compiled, so the Razor view compiler can do some magic here.

The compiler knows the type of your model because of the `@model` directive (without the @model directive the compiler falls back to `dynamic`).

If you look at the `@Html.DisplayNameFor` directive, then the `Html` instance is an object of the type `HtmlHelper<TModel>` where `TModel` is the type given by the `@model` directive. In your case is the concrete type `HtmlHelper<LoginViewModel>`.

Now the `HtmlHelper<LoginViewModel>.DisplayNameFor` method is stongly typed and the compiler can figure that '`m`' (which is only a parameter name) is of type `LoginViewModel` and that the lamdba expression returns a value from the model.

During runtime the `DisplayNameFor` method is executed by providing your model object as parameter '`m`' the expression returns the object of the model member (or the object the expression returns) and the MVC framework can inspect the object (Type, Validation Attributes, etc.) and produces the appropriate html based on internal or custom templates.

If you would just pass a string, then MVC would not be able to get the needed type and validation annotations (and much more information).

Answer (score 0):

Your first question: It passes `LogonViewModel` to `@Html.DislplayNameFor` method since you have define it on you first line as your model (`@model LoginViewModel`)

Aslo as it mentioned here:
[What is the @Html.DisplayFor syntax for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6365633/what-is-the-html-displayfor-syntax-for)

> Html.DisplayFor() will render the DisplayTemplate that matches the
>   property's type.
>
> If it can't find any, I suppose it invokes .ToString().

Answer (score 0):

`DisplayNameFor` is a *strongly typed HTML helper*. These were first introduced in [ASP.NET MVC 2](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-2-strongly-typed-html-helpers). The purpose of them (as per the linked article) is to...

> ...provide a nice way to get better type-safety within your view templates.  This enables better compile-time checking of your views (allowing you to find errors at build-time instead of at runtime), and also supports richer intellisense when editing your view templates within Visual Studio.

If you want to understand the innards of how they work, the [source code is available on GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/a78f77afde003c4a3fcf5dd7b6dc13dd9c85f825/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures/Rendering/HtmlHelperDisplayNameExtensions.cs#L41).