# OnGet() doesn't display properties in page view

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor-pages

I have a simple code where an Employee has a credit card

```cs
public class EmployeeModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly EmployeeData EmployeeData;
    private readonly CardData CardData;

    public EmployeeModel(EmployeeData EmployeeData , CardData CardData)
    {
        this.EmployeeData = EmployeeData ;
        this.CardData = CardData ;
    }

    [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
    
    [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
    public int CardID { get; set; }
    
    public Employee Employee { get; set; }
    public Card Card { get; set; }
    
    public void OnGet()
    {
        Employee = EmployeesData.GetEmployee(EmployeeID);
        Card = CardData.GetCard(CardID);              
    }
}
```

```html
@page
@model Web.Pages.EmployeeModel
@{
}
 <table class="table table-dashboard table-borderless mb-0">
              <tbody>
                 <tr class="border-bottom border-200">
                      <td>
                          <div class="flex-1">
                              <h6>ID employee</h6>
                             </div>
                        </td>
                     <td class="align-middle text-end fw-semi-bold"><span>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Employee.EmployeeID)</span></td>
                   </tr>
            </tbody>
</table>

 <table class="table table-dashboard table-borderless mb-0">
           <tbody>
                <tr class="border-bottom border-200">
                      <td>
                          <div class="flex-1">
                              <h6>ID Card</h6>
                            </div>
                            </td>
                              <td class="align-middle text-end fw-semi-bold"><span>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Card.CardID)</span></td>
                 </tr>
       </tbody>
</table>
```

I try to display the values that I have in EmployeeModel to view page, but doesn't work. I try to do the next example, to put in my OnGet(int id) parameters and it work when I have a single employee, but when I try to do something more complex and add more employee the data doesn't display itself and the table its empty:

```html
@page
@model Web.Pages.EmployeesModel

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div>
            <h1 class="display-6 text-primary">EMPLOYEES</h1>
        </div>
        <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="text-center">ID</th>
                </tr>
            <thead>
        <tbody>
                
@foreach (var employee in Model.employeeList)
   {
      <tr>
          <td class="text-center"><a asp-page="Employee" asp-route-id="@employee.EmployeeID">@employee.EmployeeID</a></td>
         </tr>
    }
              </tbody>
           </table>
     </div>
</div>
```

Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `Employee` and `Card` objects in razor as follows:

```
<td class="align-middle text-end fw-semi-bold"><span>@Model.Employee.EmployeeID</span></td>

<td class="align-middle text-end fw-semi-bold"><span>@Model.Card.CardID</span></td>
```

`@Model` allows you to access the page model object directly. In your case this would be the `EmployeeModel` instance.

You can refer to the below SO topic for the purposes of `@Html.DisplayFor`:
[What is the @Html.DisplayFor syntax for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6365633/what-is-the-html-displayfor-syntax-for)

As for the last code section I am not sure where is `@Model.employeeList` coming from. Doesn't this result to an error?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the referenced `employeeList` property in your Model that you defined. You may have it in your `EmployeesModel`, but it's not in the code you posted. Ideally, you'd want a property something like below in your model.

```cs
public List<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
```

Then, in your `OnGet()` method, populate that list from your data source.

```cs
Employees = EmployeesData.GetEmployees();
```

Then you can loop over that model property like you're trying to:

```
@foreach (var employee in Model.Employees)
{
    ...
}
```